# Is there is way to justify substrings while performing join operation

Tags: python, join, string-formatting, justify

I have to replace a word in a multiline  text at specific location specified by a line number
and word number in this line. All words all aligned in columns.

I'm using an algorithm where I'm finding word by it's coordinates.

I'm fetching a line at specified line number, splitting it in separate substrins 
and replacing a word at specified location with another word.
Then I do join (" ".join() ) and writing the modified line back into a file.
My problem is i'm loosing words alignment in modified line.
How can I justify and join at the same time? (Other words in a line also lose
alignment, not just modified word)

I think I could do it if I have used a little bit different approach by splitting a line
just at the location of the word to be modified, but I did not realized that I will lose
alignment after splitting a line at word boundaries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply formatting (with [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) or [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)) inside a list comprehension before joining:

```
''.join([format(el, '<10') for el in list_of_strings])
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_strings = ['foo', 'barbaz', 'spam-ham']
>>> ''.join([format(el, '<10') for el in list_of_strings])
'foo       barbaz    spam-ham  '
```

`<` left-aligns, `>` right-aligns and `^` centers the text in the given width (10 in the above example). For more detail on how formatting works, see the [format specification documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Demo with right-adjustment to 4 spaces:

```
>>> list_of_strings = ['foo', 'ba', 'a']
>>> ''.join([format(el, '>4') for el in list_of_strings])
' foo  ba   a'
```

Comment: You'll have to edit your question if you want to add an example.

Comment: This is what I have now: ar_str = " ".join(format(el, 'rjust(4)') for el in ar) (I used rjust(4) to create original file. Unfortunately it ddid not help

Comment: @OpenCV_fan: That is not a proper formatting specification. Use `format(el, '>4')` instead.

Comment: I missed square brakets first, than added them. Still doesn't work

Comment: @OpenCV_fan: The square brackets are optional (but make the statement faster). Try my sample first and play with that a little. And *still doesn't work* does not tell me anything. You get an error? You get weird text results? What?

Comment: I do not have an error, but still my output misaligned. I have created the file where all words ale aligned in columns. After processing, modified lines are misaligned.

Comment: So what is the alignment? What is the column widths, are the words right-aligned or left-aligned? Are the widths constant or variable? You need to tell me more, otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: You can better edit your question. I may not be able to help further until tomorrow.

Comment: arr = line.split();   arr[x] = str(corrected_value); ar_str = " ".join([format(el, '>4') for el in arr; (I'm using semicolon here instead of newline)

Comment: @OpenCV_fan: That right-aligns your strings into columns of 4 characters wide. Are your strings 4 characters long or less? If not, they are not constricted to 4 characters, they keep their original length. Is your data perhaps always delimited by 4 spaces instead? What does your *input* look like?

Comment: Your suggestion is actually correct, I played with it separately and it's fine. But in my context, it did nit work for some reason.

Comment: Perhaps you were writing to a file with a relative path, and your current working directory was not what you thought it was? In that case you probably were looking at a stale old file, not the new contents you were writing?

Comment: I was using inputfile module and inplace construct. I changed my algorithm to not use them and it works. Thank you very much fir your help and your patience. I'm very occasional user of Python, call it from applications written in other language

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting with [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) instead. If you use `/(?<= )\w/` as Regex, it'll split before each word, while preserving the whitespace. You can then join them with `''.join(...)` after replacing the word. You can append the new word with as much spaces as needed, just ask the length of the old word.

Note that this will bug if the new word is longer then the column is wide.

If I write this out in code:

```
col = 1                              # replacing second word
line = "hello  there    friend    "  # we've already fetched the line
new_word = "here"                    # the new word
word_list = re.split('(?<= )\w', line)
length = len(word_list[col])
word_list[col] = col + ((length - len(new_word)) * ' ')
new_line = ''.join(word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "this is a sample statement";

print str.rjust(50, ' '); # right justification
```

this will produce the following result:
                                                   this is a sample statement

**50 blank spaces** followed by your statement

you can try

```
print str.rjust(0, ' ')
```

to force sentences to be right justified.

Comment: I'm dealing  not with a string, but with many sub-strings after splitting a line. I'm modifying one of sub-strings and then join them